# Component verification using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

In react, to verify and show a component, we do:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(false);

<button ... onClick={() => setState(true)} />

{state && <MyComponent />}
```

but what if I want to change this code to use redux?

Comment: You can store your boolean called state in redux for sure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `react-redux` to achieve this, even though there's some boilerplate code required to set up your store if you don't have one yet.

You could do something like the following:

```
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux'
import { showViewAction } from './viewDisplaySlice'

export const MyComponent = () => {
  const shouldDisplayComponent = useSelector(state => state.shouldDisplay);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  return (
    ....
        <button
          onClick={() => dispatch(showViewAction())}
        >
          ...
        </button>
        { shouldDisplayComponent && <MyViewComponent /> }
    </div>
  );
};
```

You may find quick start guide helpful to setup store and using react-redux:
https://redux.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30408343)

Comment: @eglease you have a valid point, I updated my answer.